# How to set static IP on iPad

Tags: ipad, network, settings, ipados

My iPad keeps sending the message that it is unable to connect to the internet and my only option is to **dismiss**.

How do I find the subnet mask and ip address and router so I can manually try and set it up?

Comment: How does the iPad connect to the Internet, through WiFi or 3G?

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 7:**

> 1. Tap Settings
> 2. Tap on WiFi
> 3. Tap on your connected WiFi name
> 4. Tap the static tab and enter your addresses
> 5. Close out of the Settings and launch Safari or another network app to confirm connectivity

Comment: but if he/she is unable to connect , then wont be able to get such info, setting it static  from some other computer would solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Tap the blue arrow beside the network name in WiFi-Settings